# Why this is not a closure

Tags: javascript

Since closure is a function binded to it's lexical environment I wonder why `notAClosure` construction is not a closure:

```
let a = { b: 42 };
let notAClosure = ( param ) => { param.b++ };
let aClosure = () => { a.b++ };
notAClosure(a);
```

When `notAClosure` called, we pass to it object `a` by reference. This means that now inside closure we have access to outer scope = lexical environment.
Did I name functions right? Is `aClosure` a real closure? Is `notAClosure` really not a closure and if is is correct - then why?

Comment: A function only forms a closure if it's accessing variables that are defined in the outer scope. `param` is a local variable, so `notAClosure` isn't a closure. All functions have access to global variables, so `aClosure` isn't really a closure if `a` is global.

Comment: Why does this matter to you?  Is there a real-world scenario where there is a difference in your code?  This seems purely philosophical.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable naming is correct.

The function body of `notAClosure` does not actually refer to anything outside of its own scope. The function `aClosure` *does* refer to a variable outside of its own scope, which is `a`.

`a` is passed to `notAClosure` [by-value-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference). This places a "value" reference to `a` within the immediate scope of `notAClosure`'s function body, as `param` is an argument.

Within `aClosure`, there is no `a` in the local scope; instead, the function is (forced to) refer to the `a` in the outer scope. A slightly more complex example, to make it more obvious why it becomes a closure:

```
let x = (function() {
    let a = { b: 42 };
    return () => { a.b++; };
})();
```

`x` is assigned to a function which immediately returns another function. `x` "hides" `a` in the closure of the returned lambda function. It is **impossible** to access `a` in any way without calling `x`, but `a` still exists in memory because it is accessible within the outer scope, and thus the scope, of the returned lambda.

Answer (score 0):

your function `aClosure` is simply accessing to your `a` variable through global scope, hence, it's not a closure, you can see it actually modifies `a.b` value in this example:

```
let a = { b: 42 };
let aClosure = () => { a.b++ };

console.log(a.b);   //42
aClosure();
console.log(a.b);   //43
```

if you want to understand closures better I'd recommend [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures).

Comment: Could you please refer to any closure definition that contains a 'global' term? If no, then what is the role of globality of the outer scope for understanding closures?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but a closure happens when a function, callback or the like, have access to its 'own' values. Here I show that because of  `aClosure()` modifies the value of a.b in the global scope it is not a closure.